# Definition and motivation for Twistors

Tags: twistor

What are [Twistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twistor_theory)? Why are they important?

This particular statement in Wikipedia is intriguing

> *According to Andrew Hodges, twistor space is useful for conceptualizing the way photons travel through space, using four complex numbers.*

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36359/

Answer (score 4):

Your question can be answered at many levels. I'll keep it simple; I'm not very well versed with the grand picture.

Twistors provide an efficient (and possibly *natural*) means to encode the kinematics of massless particles and the resulting conformal symmetry. 
For a nice and clear introduction, check Witten's lecture notes from PiTP 2004:
http://www.sns.ias.edu/pitp2/2004/schedule.html