# Is there a bi-4-vector representation of the Dirac gamma matrices and the spinor?

Tags: representation-theory, dirac-equation, spinors

I learned recently that if you have the Dirac spinor represented in the Weyl (chiral) basis $\Psi = \begin{pmatrix} \psi_L \\ \psi_R \end{pmatrix}$, then given a Lorentz Transformation $\Lambda = exp[\frac{1}{2}\Omega_{\rho \sigma}M^{\rho\sigma}]$, the corresponding transformation $S[\Lambda]$ for $\Psi \rightarrow S[\Lambda]\Psi$ looks like $S[\Lambda] = exp[\frac{1}{2}\Omega_{\rho \sigma}S^{\rho\sigma}]$. In the chiral basis, this looks like each of the $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$ transforming as the different spin-1/2 representations of $so(3,1)$.

Here, the $so(3,1)$ Lie algebra is represented by the standard Lorentz matrices $M^{\rho\sigma}$ for the $x^\mu$ transformation, and the other matrices $S^{\rho\sigma}$ are the algebra generated by the gamma matrices $S^{\rho\sigma} = \frac{1}{4}[\gamma^\rho,\gamma^\sigma]$.

My question is (in probably imprecise phrasing), is it possible to choose $\gamma^\mu$ to be 8x8 matrices in such a way that $S^{\rho\sigma} = \frac{1}{4}[\gamma^\rho,\gamma^\sigma] = M^{\rho\sigma} \oplus M^{\rho\sigma} $? i.e. can we pick $\gamma^\mu$ so that the chiral components $\psi_L, \psi_R$ each transform like 4-vectors would?

Answer (score 3):

1. OP apparently wants to discuss reducible representations of the [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) $Cl(1,3;\mathbb{R})$.
2. Concretely, it seems that OP is asking about an 8-dimensional direct sum representation $$W~:=~V\oplus V$$ of 2 copies of the 4-dimensional [Dirac spinor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor) representation 
   $$V~:=~(\frac{1}{2},0) \oplus (0,\frac{1}{2}).$$
   See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. The $8\times 8$ gamma matrices 
   $$\Gamma^{\mu} ~=~\begin{pmatrix} \gamma^{\mu} & 0 \cr 0 & \gamma^{\mu} \end{pmatrix}$$
   in the $W$-representation are [block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) with 2 copies of $4\times 4$ gamma matrices in the $V$-representation.
4. The $W$-representation of the Lorentz generators take a similar block diagonal form, cf. OP's last question (v1).

Comment: But... this trivial Gamma rep will never connect the L and R components, no?

Comment: I was more so asking if there existed a $(1,0) \oplus (0,1)$ representation of the gamma matrices. 
[This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53318/) seems to say that the irreducible _complex_ representations look like V.

Comment: @Joe I see... as long as you appreciate this rep, e.g., the 0 component  in the mass term, never mixes the upper 4 with the lower four components ... what I understood to be the defining feature of *L* and *R*.... Look at $\Gamma_5$; its chiral projectors eliminate two doublets in tandem.

Comment: Hi @Qmechanic, can you refer to some book getting to some depth about this rep?

Answer (score 2):

Without full appreciation of the gist of your question (8×8?), let me just review the [chiral basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Weyl_.28chiral.29_basis) expressions for $\gamma_5$ and the Lorentz generators $S^{\mu\nu}$, which are both *block diagonal* with respect to the chiral projections, so they do not mix 
$\psi_L$ with $\psi_R$, unlike the γs:

$$\gamma^0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & I_2 \\ I_2 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad \gamma^k = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma^k \\ -\sigma^k & 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad \gamma^5 = \begin{pmatrix} -I_2 & 0 \\ 0 & I_2 \end{pmatrix},$$

$$
S^{0j}  = \tfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -\sigma^j & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma^j \end{pmatrix},  \qquad S^{jk}=\frac{i\epsilon^{kjm}}{2}  \begin{pmatrix} \sigma^m & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma^m \end{pmatrix} = i \epsilon^{kjm} \gamma_5 S^{0m}        .  $$

So,  generators (in the algebra),   manifestly constitute a reduced representation of non-interacting 2×2 blocks.

More formally, the reduced **2**   ⊕ **2** rep is 
$$
2S^{0j}=(-\sigma^j)\oplus \sigma^j, \qquad 2S^{jk}=i\epsilon^{kjm} (\sigma^m\oplus \sigma^m). 
$$

Comment: I understand this part. In the Weyl representation of $\gamma^\mu$ that you gave, the generated $S^{\mu\nu}$ are block diagonal, and each block corresponds to the $SL(2,C)$ Lie Algebra.  My question was asking whether we can pick the gamma matrices to be 8x8 real matrices so that $S^{\mu\nu}$ are block diagonal and correspond to the $SO(3,1)$ Lie Algebra. If this were true, we could treat each component, $\psi_L, \psi_R$ as transforming like a 4-vector, by the expression for $S[\Lambda]$ given above.

Comment: ?? What's wrong with this representation? Of course the algebra of the 6 *S*s is the algebra of SO(3,1); how could it fail that? It is a bi-spinor rep, acting on 4D: $\psi_L\oplus \psi_R$ rep. You want to add the two spin 1/2s of each block into a spin 1 of each?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the representation per-say. I meant that I wanted the 6 Ss as the same matrices as the Lorentz Algebra as regularly viewed in 4d space, or as a direct sum of them. I want to know if we can express the spinor as two spin 1's instead of two spin 1/2's by some other choice of gamma matrices that aren't in $C^{4x4}$, but in $R^{8x8}$. I haven't seen anywhere that it can't be done explicitly, but I haven't seen its impossibility stated, and I'm having trouble constructing them myself, which is why I'm asking on stackexchnge

Comment: I see. Your want the [spinor map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Relation_to_the_M.C3.B6bius_group) extended to the Lorentz group. It maps 2x2 complex matrices to real vectors. It is the basis of twistor theory, but a very different question.

Comment: You seem to be trying to reinvent [APS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation_in_the_algebra_of_physical_space), a sorry tale....

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies, these seem like good resources. Would you be able to explain how my question is related to twistors and APS,  and why this is a sorry tale? It's a bit tough to get the big-picture ideas from the Wikipedia links.

Comment: Sorry, not I. You might be able to re-write your question in light of [36359](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36359/gentle-introduction-to-twistors).