# Book recommendations about differential geometry for the study of twistors

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, twistor

I'm in my first year as a PhD student and I'm trying to learn about twistors. I found the question about the [book recommendations for twistor theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36359/), but it quickly became clear that my knowledge of differential geometry is vague at best. I looked at some recommendations for differential geometry, but either they're too basic and don't cover what I need, either they're too advanced and already assume a mountain of dif. geo. knowledge.

So my question is, *what are some good books about differential geometry to be able to understand twistor theory*?